# New to Java(Inheritance): Declaration of a subclass in main program

Tags: java, inheritance

Im having trouble on how to declarate a Sub-Class in my main program.

I have my abstract superClass called **Shapes**, and 4 subclasses (**Rectangle, Triangle, Circle, Square**);

I know that if I want to use the superClass I create a new variable:

```
private Shapes shapes;
```

Then I assign the variable to the superClass:

```
shapes = new Shapes();
```

I thouht you could declare a subclass like this:

```
private Shapes square;
//
square = new Square();//Square is a sub-class of Shapes.
```

Help, please.

Comment: Its completely unclear for me what you are asking

Comment: Post [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Lets start with cosmetic changes first till we understand your problem, you can rename the class `Shape` instead of `Shapes`.

Comment: The way you use the words does not conform to their meaning. Maybe you want to start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) first.

Comment: @singhakash Sorry I'm new, when you create a Superclass you can create a subclass of that superclass, and I'm having trouble on how to use the subclass on my main program.

Answer (score 1):

You are not declaring classes above, you are creating pointers and instantiating objects.  You need to actually use the class keyword like so:

```
public class Shape {
}
```

And when you create a subclass, it would be

```
public class Square extends Shape {
}
```

If you create objects it in your main, for example, it could look like:

```
Shape s = new Square();
```

or

```
Square square = new Square();
```

But that is just the way you create the objects, not classes.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 aspects.

- Creating a class hierarchy

  ```
  public class Square extends Shape {
  }
  ```
- Making base class pointer or reference point to child class object.

  ```
   Shape aSquare = new Square();
  ```